# How can I push a git repo to a remote server through ssh?

Tags: git, ssh, server, phpstorm

I have a remote server which I can access through SSH. How can I push my local git repo there? The server doesn't have git installed, I want to do everything from my IDE (PhpStorm)

So far the only solution for me is to sync the local repo's directory with the one on the remote server with WinSCP but that's messy and I don't want another application for a job what git supposed to do.

Comment: If you want to use git, you should install git, and - duh - use git. It does not need a server process on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the remote server needs to have .git installed. There is no way around it!

If the server has .git installed, you can add a `remote` repository from your local machine. You can do this by typing `git remote add branchname user@domain.tld/path/to/your/repo.git` into your terminal.

This command will connect your local repository to your remote server, where your website is sitting. No need for a git account.

This guy explains it really well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qIK8ZC9BnU

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a git executable on your server that your local git executable can talk to (over ssh), you must be able to access the file system on the server directly on your client.  This means SMB or NFS or similar.

Under Linux the "sshfs" command allows "mounting" a remote directory on a server reachable through ssh as a local directory.  This allows git to work directly with the files on the remote server.  I am not aware of a similar solution for Windows.  I would suggest installing git remotely as this is what git was designed for - it will work better.